# Is your father name is x?

Tags: sentence-construction

I like to know whether expressing, 'is your father name is x'  is right or wrong..

If it is used to taunt a person, for example is your father name is laden, kind of expression.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "father name"? Your father's given name/first name? Your patronymic? Your father's family name? The given/first name for you that your father chose?

Comment: No . When A is talking to B. If A want to know whether x is B's father name or not.

Comment: Yes, but what would A mean by "father name"? That is not a term typically used in English, and it's not clear what it *would* mean.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be [conflating](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conflation) two methods...

**Statement**

> Your father's name **is** Johnson.

**Question**

> **Is** your father's name Johnson?

The "is" moves to distinguish statement from question.
It cannot be in both places at once.

You also need the possessive apostrophe+s, "the name of your father" is "your father's name"

Comment: A upon knowing foolish arguments of B,tauntingly want to say whether his father name is bin laden though he know laden is not his father's name.

Comment: The intent is not important, content &/or tone of voice will convey that. You merely need to phrase it correctly as a question rather than a statement.

Comment: If it is expressed as statement, will that be a valid grammatical expression?

Comment: What part of my answer as it stands is unclear?

Comment: @Tetsujin - It wouldn't surprise me if the OP is having trouble understanding the notion of "conflating" (which means, "mixing up by combining").

Comment: @J.R. - you may be right. Link to Wikipedia definition, as the most expanded I could find, added.